# How to pin the Desktop folder to the left?

Tags: files

I can see the Desktop folder on the left. But on my other computer, I can't see it.
How to pin it to the left?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: **Welcome to AskUbuntu!** Please provide what OS you are using, which version, etc. Also, I can see the desktop folder on the left side. Is this the screenshot of your other computer?? If not, then add its screenshot by using the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499577/edit) and add it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the file explorer, as shown in the screenshot, you can see the Desktop folder.

You can *click and drag* the folder to the left panel. The system will automatically ask for a new bookmark option. The new Desktop shortcut will be created.
Other important folders can also be added to bookmarks in such a way.